# Weird points calculation at Qantas Frequent Flyer

Tags: loyalty-programs, qantas, tam-airlines

My wife and I travelled with LAN/TAM last year, together.

I bought 2 tickets at the same time/session, that is, same price and conditions for both of us.

I entered both of our Qantas Frequent Flyer numbers at the time of the purchase. LAN/TAM is a partner of Qantas, they also do codeshare in this flight. LAN's website had a field to enter the Qantas Frequent Flyer when buying the tickets, that's what I used.

However, the points we earned and our Frequent Flyer statements are totally different.

We made a flight from New Zealand to Brazil with stopover in Chile.

My statement looks like this:

```
Date         Description                                                         Points
29/OCT/15    LA 753 DISCOUNT ECONOMY/ECONOMY 24OCT15 GUARULHOS INTL/SANTIAGO       402
29/OCT/15    LA 801 DISCOUNT ECONOMY/ECONOMY 25OCT15 SANTIAGO/AUCKLAND           1,504
08/OCT/15    LA 5951 ECONOMY 01OCT15 SANTIAGO/GUARULHOS INTL                     1,607
08/OCT/15    LA 800 DISCOUNT ECONOMY/ECONOMY 01OCT15 AUCKLAND/SANTIAGO           1,504
```

That gives me a total of `5,017` points.

Hers statement looks like this:

```
Date         Description                                                         Points
01/DEC/15   LA 801 ECONOMY 25OCT15 SANTIAGO/AUCKLAND                             6,014
01/DEC/15   LA 753 ECONOMY 24OCT15 GUARULHOS INTL/SANTIAGO                       1,607
```

Her total was `7,621` points.

My question is, "why is everything different", but I can breakdown in 5 questions:

1. Why are the dates different?
2. Why are the description for flights LA 801 and LA 753 different?
3. Why did she earn more points than me?
4. Why didn't she earn points for flights LA 800 and LA 5951 (NZ to Brazil)?
5. What should I do?

More info:

Our E-tickets, for both of us, shows that the flight NZ <-> Chile were *Economy-O* and Chile <-> Brazil were *Economy-B*.

Also, there is a *Fare* code `OEESP60Y` for all flights and for both of us, which I don't know what it means.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the two tickets had the same price? One statements states "Discount Economy" while the other one states "Economy". This suggests that the booking classes ("L","T","W", ...) were different, which leads to different prices.

Comment: I bought them together, when selecting the number of passengers I put 2 adults and that's it. Same price, same everything. We are both at the same level in the loyalty program too.

Comment: Do you have the boarding passes? Does it mention a code there? Or on your E-ticket, does it say class 'Y' or 'T' or  something else?

Comment: Also, did you manually claim the points for either case, or did they just show up?  It's quite unusual for a flight in October not to register before December.

Comment: IMHO, the big question really is how many miles should you actually have received for those flights? What was the fare for each of the flights, for each of the passengers? It is possible (though unlikely) that there was only one seat in discount economy available, so one got the cheaper fare (and the lower amount of miles) while the other got a more expensive fare and more miles. Or maybe there was a special offer like a discount for a second passenger on the same booking? Or maybe age-related discounts? The actual fares will tell us.

Comment: The miles shown on your statement match those you would get for a "deep discount economy" fare (booking classes A, G, N, O, Q), which give 25% of the miles, while those on your wife's match regular economy (booking classes B, H, K, Y), which give 100% of the miles. Also, are you sure the first pair of flights is not on a previous statement in her case?

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a mistake: the airline was LAN/TAM, not Qantas, but I added the Qantas Frequent Flyer when I bought the tickets. I've edited my question and added more information regarding the fare codes.

Comment: @MarkMayo I don't have the boarding passes, I've edited my question to add the codes I found in the E-tickets.

Comment: @jcaron Did they make 2 mistakes in my wife's flight? Used the wrong booking class (it should be the 25% one) and not giving points for the NZ -> Brazil flights? I've edited my question to add info about the codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the posting dates ("Dates" on your pasted data), it would appear that they neglected to post your wife's flights right after your travel.  Then when they did post them, they posted them as full fares rather than discounted.

The full fare points could be a gesture of apology for the delay in posting, a result of them being unable to determine the original fare class or simply a mistake.

For the missing flights, you will likely need to send Qantas copies of her boarding passes for the return flights.  Boarding passes are the only real proof you checked in. Of course, the downside, is that armed with boarding passes and ticket number, they may realize the outbound flight was credited wrong and adjust those points down to the same level as yours.